# CMFCToolbar::RestoreOriginalState() not available (MS VS2015 Bug?)

Tags: mfc

I want to use [MSDN CMFCToolbar::RestoreOriginalState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984480.aspx#cmfctoolbar__restoreoriginalstate)

```
CMFCToolBar m_wndToolBar;
m_wndToolBar.RestoreOriginalstate();
```

But when I try this to compile in VS2015 I get this error

> .. \mainfrm.cpp(428): error C2039: 'RestoreOriginalstate': is not a member of 'CMFCToolBar'

??

In < VS2010, I can compile this with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is named **CMFCToolBar::RestoreOriginalState**.

All C++ version in all time use match case! Your code reads `RestoreOriginalstate`. state must be written in uppercase!

Comment: Bingo! I did not see this slight difference. However this uppercase won't compile in <VS2010. MS has corrected the declaration.

Comment: "All C++ version in all time use match case"  Where come this statement?

Comment: See standard. Or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers). Quote: "Identifiers are case-sensitive (lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct), and every character is significant."

Comment: Ironically the link provided at the top of the question uses a capital **S**. And the question title itself. :)